# C++ abi compatability without pimpl using abstract class

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, abi, pimpl-idiom

Suppose I have a class `B_Impl` which inherits and implements a pure abstract class `B` (not containing any data-fields).

Suppose class `A` uses `B_Impl` via `B*` only.

If I add a field to `B_Impl.h` (clearly, not included by `A`), will ABI compatability be preserved?

I thought, that it will not be preserved, -- after reading https://wiki.qt.io/D-Pointer.

But I can see in my app that after changing `B_Impl.h`, the object file for class `A` is **not** regenerated and everything still works great.

Maybe, this is because in my app `A` and `B` are part of the same app and `B` is not a library called by `A`? Or is it because `vtable` is located as the very first field in the memory always and adding another field to `B_Impl.h` (which is "beneath" `B`) does not change the fact that `vtable` is the first field? Or is this stuff somehow corrected by the linker rather than by re-generating `A`-object-file?

Honestly, I am a bit confused here:

- Is this ABI problem is only about libraries?
- How can I modulate the situation in my app (where A uses B not as a library) when I call `B*` and get some seg-fault by changing `B_Impl.h`, (i.e. by ignoring the Pimpl principle, suggested in the article), and not re-generating `A`-object-file?
- Or is it true that if I use a class via interface `B*` I can change its `B_Impl.h` as much as I could by adding new fields etc. and not being afraid that I will have to re-compile `A` that uses `B` directly in the same app or re-compile `C` that uses `B` as a call to a shared library? Thank you for attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I add a field to B_Impl.h (clearly, not included by A), will ABI compatability be preserved?

Yes. If a translation unit doesn't include the definition of `B_Impl`, then changes to `B_Impl` won't affect the compatibility.

The interface compatibility - whether it is API or ABI - matters only when the interface is used. In your example, the interface of `B` is used; not the interface of `B_Impl`.

> Is this ABI problem is only about libraries?

Whether `B_Impl` is in a library or not shouldn't matter.

Comment: But I call methods of B_Impl using B* pointer. I mean in reality I use B_Impl instance even though my A class does not know it. Is it not a problem because vtable is located as the first data field or something?

Comment: @JenyaKh The translation unit that creates the `B_Impl` instance will take care that the vtable is correct. That TU will need to be recompiled if `B_Impl` changes.

Comment: I am sorry maybe I formulated my question not in a best way. I mean -- I understand that the oject B_Impl itself will be created by a TU that creates it. But my point is that the layout of B_Impl's fileds could change. And I am a bit confused why it will not affect `A`-class using `B*`? It still needs to know some offsets of  B_Impl or something. And it's a bit strange to me that the internal structure of B_Impl  beneath B does not introduce any linkage or execution problems. Besides, why does not Qt just uses interfaces everywhere and why do they need the Pimpl-idiom at all?

Comment: @JenyaKh `But my point is that the layout of B_Impl's fileds could change.` Consider this: `B_Impl` doesn't have to be the only class derived from `B`. You could have `B_Impl1` and `B_Impl2` each of which derive from `B` and each of which can have completely different layout with no common members at all. `A` can use both of them equally through the pointer to `B`. Given that you can substitute one derived class with another class without problem, it should be intuitive that changing the derived class would be just as fine.

Comment: @JenyaKh  `It still needs to know some offsets of B_Impl or something.` It doesn't need to. You need to know offsets in order to access members directly. But you cannot access members directly without having defined the class first. Which you are saying is not included. Everything that has to do with the layout has to happen in TU that includes the definition.

Comment: @JenyaKh `Besides, why does not Qt just uses interfaces everywhere and why do they need the Pimpl-idiom at all?` I'm not author of Qt so I don't know why they made choices that they have. Inheritance has limitations that don't apply to PIMPL. Think about it from the other direction: Why would Qt need to use inheritance at all since they can just use PIMPL instead?